# WSO2 - Enterprise integrator 6.5.0 returning PDF

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We have an api that returns a PDF in the following format:

{
"binary": "binarycontent"
}

how can we handle this response in the sequence to return a PDF?

Note: we added under axis2.xml the message

```
Under message formatters:
<messageFormatter contentType="application/pdf" 
                    class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>

Under message builders
<messageBuilder contentType="application/pdf" 
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

We tried to loopback the response as it is but it did not work, it is returning an empty response with no option to download the file.

Comment: Add the integration source so we can get a better understanding of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
           <property expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" name="HTTP_STATUS_CODE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <filter regex="true" source="get-property('HTTP_STATUS_CODE') = '200'">
            <then>
                <property expression="json-eval($.binary)" name="base64Response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <log category="INFO" level="custom">
                    <property name="Encoded PDF " expression="get-property('base64Response')"/>
                </log>
                
                <!-- Set the HTTP status code for the response -->
                <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="default" type="STRING" value="200"/>

                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:binary>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('base64Response')"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
       
                <script language="js">
                    var binaryNode = mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstOMChild();  
                    binaryNode.setBinary(true);
                </script>
                <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/pdf"/>
            </then>
            <else> // handle error </else> </filter>
```